# How to set up an initial repository with some branches to operate on?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-git

I've been chipping away at trying to better understand how to set up the initial state of a test within my application. The initial setup that I need is fairly minimal:

1. Set up a git repository for my tests to run on.
2. Create a few branches.
3. Create a file on one of the branches.

I think that from this setup I can get further on my own. I've looked at the `common_test.go` package and there seems to be some helpful structs and functions here, but they depend on fixtures from `go-get/fixtures`, which seem to only pull remote repositories.

Pulling something remote is not necessarily what I need to do, so that seems to be out-of-scope.

I suspect I need to do something with the billy filesystem interface, but I haven't quite figured out how to leverage this to do what I need yet.

So far I have something, but it doesn't work as expected. For example, when I create all of the branches on the `repo`, I am unable to iterate over them with `ForEach()`, at all. In fact, I don't even think the function passed to `ForEach()` gets called. What I find strange, though, is if I do something like `b, err := repo.Branch("refs/heads/JOB-62131/JOB-76475/add-location-timers-to-fms")` then I can get that branch back without error.

```golang
func TestCommonSuiteExample(t *testing.T) {
    repo, _ := git.Init(memory.NewStorage(), memfs.New())
    branchNames := []string{
        "refs/heads/JOB-62131/JOB-76475/add-location-timers-to-fms",
        "refs/heads/JOB-62131/JOB-76477/store-feature-enablement",
        "refs/heads/JOB-62131/JOB-77400/show-modal-dialogue-on-disablement",
    }

    for _, b := range branchNames {
        opts := &config.Branch{Name: b}
        err := repo.CreateBranch(opts)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    branches, _ := repo.Branches()

        // Branches don't seem to get iterated over here, not sure why.
    branches.ForEach(func(ref *plumbing.Reference) error {
        fmt.Print(ref.Name().IsBranch()) 
        return nil
    })
}
```